# JQuery's .click triggering on child elements

Tags: jquery

I have a page with multiples divs like this

```
<div class="bigbox">
    <a href="http://www.somestuff.com">some stuff</a>
    more elements
</div>
```

I'm trying to make each div open the link inside it when clicked and tried like that:

```
$('div.bigbox').each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(){
        window.open($(this).find('a').attr("href"));
})})
```

But when clicking on the actual link, it will open it twice. Any suggestion to not have .click trigger when clicking on the link inside my div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're pretty close with your code. Try this:

```
$('div.bigbox').click(function()
{
    window.open($(this).find('a').attr('href'));
    return false;
});
```

The `return false` should keep it from opening more than once, so give that a try and see how it works.

Comment: Tried this one first and it indeed works. 
I had only tried adding `return false` to the `a` element to try to block it when javascript is enabled, but that was totally blocking the link.

Answer (score 2):

By *open twice*, I assume you meant that the link is followed in the original window as well as the new window.

Just add `return false`, or `e.preventDefault()` to stop this.

```
$('div.bigbox').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    window.open($(this).find('a').attr("href"));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like:

```
$('div.bigbox').find('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

That would prevent any  tags iniside .bigbox divs from firing their click events.

Answer (score 1):

you want your handler to be called when the div is clicked, but not when the link inside the div is called?

how about adding

```
$('div.bigbox').each(function( event ){
  $(this).click(function(){

    // only perform the action if the div itself was clicked
    if ( event.target == this ) {
      window.open($(this).find('a').attr("href"));
    }
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you'd be better off just doing this:

```
<a href="http://www.somestuff.com">
    <div class="bigbox">
        More elements
    </div>
</a>
```

If you'd rather use javascript, you can always just do this:

```
$('div.bigbox').click(function(e)
{
    window.open($(this).find('a').attr('href'));
    e.preventDefault();
});
```